# What is Wolverine's full name?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine

I know his name is Logan, but I don't actually know if it's his first name, or last name, or if he even has a first and a last name.
To my understanding he ran away from his parents and **chose** to name himself Logan, but I'm fairly new to the Marvel universe and I could very well be 100% wrong.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

He was born as **James Howlett**, but he adopted the nickname 'Logan' to keep his identity secret. (Logan was the last name of his groundskeeper). Rose was the one who gave him the name.

[image]

(Jemas, Bill, Quesada, Joe, Jenkins, Paul (w). Origin (2001–2002), Marvel Comics)
[image]

From [marvel.com](http://marvel.com/universe/Wolverine_%28James_Howlett%29):

> Born the second son of wealthy landowners John and Elizabeth Howlett
>   in Alberta, Canada during the late 19th Century [...]  James also assumed the name of "Logan" in order to hide his identity.

Comment: Made me curious: **Gulo gulo** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverine

Comment: It can be noted that "Logan" is a bit more than *just* an assumed nickname. Thomas Logan was his actual birth father, though IIRC, James was not aware of that when he began using the name.

Comment: @phantom42 Correct. That his father is named Logan is really just a reference for readers, though. In the universe there really isn't anyone that knows the significance of this (aside from people and entities like the Watcher).

Comment: Yes that is right James howlett is Logan Logan was the last name of his grounds keeper rose was the one who gave him the name he was adopted aswell